# Does anybody know a tutorial for designing the Mountain Lion background pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, patterns, metal

Does anybody know a tutorial for designing the OS X Mountain Lion background pattern? I am referring to this commonly used background pattern:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll take some tweaking to get the result you want, but you can achieve something similar using the Crosshatch filter:

### Step 1: Start a new document with a layer filled the color of your choice

[image: Step 1]

### Step 2: Create a new layer, fill it with black, add noise with `Filter -> Noise -> Add Noise...`

[image: Step 2]

### Step 3: Add a Cross Hatch filter to the noise: `Filter -> Brush Strokes -> Crosshatch...`

[image: Step 3]

### Step 4: Set the blending mode of that layer to `Screen` and reduce the opacity to about 40%

[image: Step 4]

### Step 5: Rotate the crosshatch layer by 45° and then crop

[image: Step 5]

### Result:

[image: Result]

Some fine tuning: I added a Gaussian Blur to make the crosshatches a little less harsh.

If you're alright with it not tiling nicely then you can add a gradient to the base color layer.

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Thanks John. One question: how would one know what tools should be used and what needs to be done to achieve a desired effect? Experience? Playing with lots of tools/filters? Are there any helpful books?

Comment: A combination of experience and playing with the filters. I've never tried making this before, but I recognized that the "brushed aluminum" looked similar to the effect the Crosshatch filter produces. From there I fiddled with the settings until it looked similar to the sample.

Comment: I got the same effect using motion blur with a high pixel setting. More than one way to skin a cat :)